# Python function that returns the total cost of meals and drink, python error

Tags: python, function, percentage

The function takes two values, the cost of the meals and drinks before GST.
Before GST is applied, a 30% discount needs to be applied to the drinks cost.
Goods and services tax (GST) needs to be added to the meal and drinks cost, GST is set to 15%, here is what I have, it seems I'm getting both answers as the same instead of separate answers which are 11.5 and 17.02.

```
def dinner_calculator(meal_cost, drinks_cost):
    """ Returns the total cost of the meal """
    meal_cost = 1.15
    drinks_cost = 1.30
    return total_cost = meal_cost, drinks_cost


total_cost = dinner_calculator(10, 0)
print(round(total_cost, 2))     

11.5

total_cost = dinner_calculator(12, 4)
print(round(total_cost, 2)) 

17.02
```

Comment: is this the actual code you use? or just a mockup? If that's the case please show us the code that is giving you trouble

Comment: Please a) fix your code (you have pasted part of the function twice) and b) explain exactly where you are having trouble.

Comment: Your description of what the code's supposed to do contradicts itself, and there appears to be a typo in your code. BTW, the Python `%` operator is **not** used to calculate percentages.

Comment: this has nothing to do with gstreamer ...

Comment: @tarynsayers A guy at Canterbury Uni sets this as a homework question, or used to. I've pointed him at this to see if he can help.

Answer (score 2):

First of all `meal_cost = 15%` does not means anything for Python.
When you have to apply a percentage calculation, consider using a factor instead:

```
meal_factor = 1.15
```

multiplying a number with this factor will actually compute this number + 15%. You can do the same with drinks.

---

Then `return total_cost = meal_cost, drinks_cost` tries to return the result of an assignation, which is faulty.
What you want to do is direclty return the result of the values

```
return meal_cost, drinks_cost
```

or use an intermediate variable:

```
total_cost = meal_cost, drinks_cost
return total_cost
```

---

Finally, remember that by doing `meal_cost, drinks_cost` you just make a tuple, but not an addition.
What you want is probably this:

```
total_cost = meal_cost + drinks_cost
```

---

As a conclusion, you probably should give a look at the official Python tutorial for [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/index.html) or [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.5/index.html)